# creating dimensional array with 2 single array

Tags: php, arrays

i have 2 arrays and i want 2 create 2D array for create mysql record

```
      Array
      (
           [0] => a
           [1] => b
           [2] => c
       )
       Array
       (
           [0] => 1
           [1] => 2
           [2] => 3
         )
```

i want 2 merge them into 2 dimensional array like this

```
      Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [designation_id] => 1
        [judge_name] => a
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [designation_id] => 2
        [judge_name] => b
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [designation_id] => 3
        [judge_name] => c
    )

 )
```

i use array_merge_recursive and it generates result like this

```
  Array
 (
     [0] => a
     [1] => b
     [2] => c
     [3] => 1
     [4] => 2
     [5] => 3
  )
```

Comment: If you got what you need from any of the answers (or not) you should comment (and maybe accept one) and let people know. The same goes for your previous questions.

Comment: Drat, my answer was too late into the game =/

Answer (score 3):

Assuming there will always be the same amount of values in `$array1` as there are in `$array2`..

```
$array1 = Array("a","b","c");
$array2 = Array(1,2,3);
$newArray = Array();

foreach($array1 as $key => $arr1Val){
    $newArray[$key]['designation_id'] = $array2[$key];
    $newArray[$key]['judge_name'] = $array1[$key];
}
```

Of course, you will have to alter `$array1` and `$array2` to your needs, but you understand the basic idea. Check it [here](http://codepad.org/42aHEq0C).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `$array1` is the `judge_name` and `$array2` is the `designation_id`

```
$newArray = array();

for($i=0; $i<count($array1); $i++)
{
    $newArray[] = array(
        'designation_id' => $array2[$i],
        'judge_name' => $array1[$i]
    );
}
```

**[Codepad Demo](http://codepad.org/Sfv3aLPg)**

**Outputs**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [designation_id] => 1
            [judge_name] => a
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [designation_id] => 2
            [judge_name] => b
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [designation_id] => 3
            [judge_name] => c
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

simple as hell

```
$array1 = array('a', 'b', 'c');
$array2 = array(1,2,3);

$merged = array();
foreach($array1 as $key => $value)
{
    $merged[$key] = array(
        'judge_name' => $value,
        'designation_id' => array_key_exists($key, $array2) ? $array2[$key] : null
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that both arrays are of same size

```
$length = count($array1);
$finalArray = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $temp = array();
    $temp['designation_id']  = $array1[$i];
    $temp['judge_name']  = $array2[$i];
    $finalArray[$i] = $temp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have PHP >= 5.3 you could use [`MultipleIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.multipleiterator.php) for that purpose:

```
$designations = array(1, 2, 3);
$judges = array('a', 'b', 'c');

$mt = new MultipleIterator(MultipleIterator::MIT_KEYS_ASSOC);
$mt->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($designations), "designation_id");
$mt->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($judges), "judge_name");

$final = iterator_to_array($mt, false);
print_r($final);
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/sovb6u)

It iterates over multiple arrays, taking a value from each array at every iterator; you can assign a key for each array that will be used to form a single array item.

Afterwards you convert the results into an array using `iterator_to_array()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = array('a', 'b', 'c');
$b = array(1,2,3);
$output = array_map(function($i, $j){
    return array(
        'judge_name'     => $j,
        'designation_id' => $i
    );
}, $a, $b);

var_dump($output);
```

Outputs

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["judge_name"]=>
    int(1)
    ["designation_id"]=>
    string(1) "a"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["judge_name"]=>
    int(2)
    ["designation_id"]=>
    string(1) "b"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["judge_name"]=>
    int(3)
    ["designation_id"]=>
    string(1) "c"
  }
}
```

Comment: Try changing the closure to return an array item instead and use the output of `array_map()` directly to populate `$output`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$new1=array("a","b","c");
$new2=array("1","2","3");
$req=array();
$d=0;
foreach($new1 as $value1)
{
    foreach($new2 as $value2)
    {
        $req[$d]["designation_id"]=$value1;
        $req[$d]["judge_name"]=$value2;
        $d++;
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($req);
```